# Ambiguous Class Namespace Issue

Tags: c++, namespaces, objective-c++, classname

I... feel really silly asking this, but I'm not sure how to resolve the problem.

This is a little snippit of my code (Objective-C++):

```
#include "eq/eq.h"
namespace eqOther
{
    class Window : public eq::Window //<-- Error occurs here
    {
    public:
        Window( eq::Pipe* parent ) : eq::Window( parent ) {}

        void popup();

    protected:
        virtual ~Window() {}

        virtual bool processEvent( const eq::Event& event );

    private:

    };
}
```

And the error I'm getting is: `Use of 'Window' is ambiguous` and it says it's declared in X.h as `typedef XID Window` and in window.h as `class eq::Window` which is its superclass.

The class I'm declaring should be in `namespace eqOther` yea?  `eqOther::Window` is different than `eq::Window`!?

I feel soooo dumb, but I just don't see what I've done wrong...

Comment: Are you getting a warning, or an error message?

Comment: I would use `::eq::Window` just to be sure.  But I can't see what you've done wrong either.  It's complaining that your type name clashes with a typedef defined in the rood namespace.  Did you do an include of `X.h` inside the namespace declaration for `eqOther`?

Comment: you sure you don't have some "using namespace eq;" somewhere in your headers?

Comment: Augh!  That was it @Dmitry!  Stupid!  And of course, it didn't throw any other errors because "window.h" was included after "stupidme.h" and everything else was before it.

Sigh... thanks guys!  @Dmitry, put your comment as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have some `using namespace eq;` somewhere in your headers